# Sum to a certain value of a group of integers

Tags: algorithms, integers

Take a group filled with an arbitrary number of random integers. Is there any way of finding out whether it is possible for the sum of the integers can equal a certain number, with the condition that any of the integers can (but do not have to) be multiplied by 0 or -1?

The only possible solution I could think of was to have the algorithm test all possible sums with each integer multiplied by 0 or -1, but this seems to be extremely inefficient, especially with larger groups of integers.

Example:

> 2 40 6 7 6 2 can sum to 30 ([0*2] [40] [-1*6] [0*7] [-1*6] [2])

Comment: Are you allowed to sort them ?

Comment: Yes, they can be sorted.

Comment: Have a look at the subset sum problem. So no, in general, there is no algorithm that is always fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically [the subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is well-studied.  In particular, there is no efficient algorithm for solving all instances of this problem.

There's a small twist in your version of the problem: you allow multiplying numbers by -1.  However, your problem can still be reduced to the subset problem, by simply appending the negation of all numbers in your list to the list; then you have an instance of the subset sum problem.  For instance, if your list is 2 40 6 7 6 2, you ask whether a subset of 2 40 6 7 6 2 -2 -40 -6 -7 -6 -2 can sum to 30.  That's an instance of the subset sum problem.

If the numbers are not too large, you can use [the standard dynamic programming algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution), and it will be pretty efficient.  But this fails if the numbers are large.

Comment: I don't immediately see how to show NP-hardness of the OP's problem. ​ ​